# What happens if I change the password of the Sales Cloud Connector User in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder

I need to log in as the Sales Cloud Connector User that is set up in the Marketing Cloud. I will need to reset the password for this user to do this.

What happens if I do this? Will my established journeys still run? Will my data stream sync continue to run? Are there any other negative outcomes? Does the Contact Model fall over?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question - in my case (YMMV) it didn't break anything.